# Wordpress permalinks is wrong. It wants me to change my htaccess file. But then site crashes

Tags: htaccess

When I try to access wp-admin, and such, wordpress links me wrong, the link is like duplicate. I've read somewhere that I should resave my permalinks. But when I press save then I get this:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php?settings-updated=true
```

And at the bottom of permalinks page there is this text that says I should copy paste some code into `.htaccess` (this code):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase example.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . example.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But if I do that then I get a 500 server error when I try to visit my homepage.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Where is WordPress installed? Where is your `.htaccess` file located? Do you have a subdirectory called `example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the recommended `.htaccess` files for WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), there's a difference (yours has `example.com/`, whereas the recommendation is `/`.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I don't know if that's what's causing the duplication of `example.com/wp-admin/` in your URL. I suspect that is due to something incorrect in your `wp-config.php` file, or perhaps in your database.

Comment: What you have posted is what I have right now. I thought that was what was causing it.